# Play framework 2.7.* Java - HTTP Context Deprecated - Token Based Authentication

Tags: java, playframework, http-headers

Currently upgrading play framework to 2.7.* I'm getting an error response due to deprecation in the security authenticator class of HTTP.Context class

The application was on Play 2.6.* and auth was working as designed. If I roll back to 2.6.* the authentication works well. Essentially I'm hoping to return the auth token as a String.

```
    @Override
    public String getUsername(Http.Request ctx) {

        Optional token = getTokenFromHeader(ctx);
        if(token.isPresent()){
            UserAccount userAccount = UserAccount.find.query().where().eq("authtoken",token.toString()).findOne();

            if (userAccount != null){
                //ctx.args.put("userAccount", userAccount);
                //String resp = Optional.<String>ofNullable(null).orElse(orelesMethod());
                String resp = Optional.<String>ofNullable(null).orElse(userAccount.authtoken);
                return resp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Http.Request ctx) {
        Logger.info("onUnauthorized");
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        result.put("error","Unauthorized, Please login");
        return status(401,result);
    }

    private Optional getTokenFromHeader(Http.Request ctx) {
        return ctx.header("X-AUTH-TOKEN");
    }

}
```

Original Code is as below

```
public class Secured extends Security.Authenticator{

    @Override
    public String getUsername(Http.Context ctx) {
        String token = getTokenFromHeader(ctx);
        if(token != null){
            UserAccount userAccount = UserAccount.find.query().where().eq("authtoken",token).findOne();
            if (userAccount != null){
                ctx.args.put("userAccount", userAccount);
                return userAccount.authtoken;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Result onUnauthorized(Http.Context ctx) {
        Logger.info("onUnauthorized");
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        result.put("error","Unauthorized, Please login");
        return status(401,result);
    }

    private String getTokenFromHeader(Http.Context ctx) {
        String[] authTokenHeaderValues = ctx.request().headers().get("X-AUTH-TOKEN");
        if ((authTokenHeaderValues != null) && (authTokenHeaderValues.length == 1) && (authTokenHeaderValues[0] != null)) {
            return authTokenHeaderValues[0];
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Error response
`return type java.lang.String is not compatible with java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>`

Comment: Are you sure the code you posted is the code you got the error on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play 2.7 has some changes in Security.Authenticator class. Now it has two methods named getUsername.

You override method with Request param, so you should return Optional not String.

Take a look on Authenticator code:

```java
    /**
     * Handles authentication.
     */

    public static class Authenticator extends Results {

        @Deprecated
        public String getUsername(Context ctx) {
            return ctx.session().get("username");
        }

        // You override this method
        public Optional<String> getUsername(Request req) {
            return req.session().getOptional("username");
        }

        ...

    }
```